# AS3 gotoAndStop events trigger enterFrame but only after loading external files

Tags: actionscript-3, events, frame

We've got a complex AS3 project that loads in various external files. What we've discovered is that once this has happened, gotoAndStop commands (not necessarily on the externally loaded files) trigger the EnterFrame event we have attached to the main timeline. This leads to some really weird results and occasionally complete crashes.

The example we found that showed us we had a problem looked something like this:

(Bit of code in one place)

```
trace("goto 1")
tClip.gotoAndStop("on")
trace("goto 1 done")
```

(bit of code somewhere else)

```
trace("goto 2")
tClip2.gotoAndStop("off")
trace("goto 2 done")
```

output:

```
//goto 1
//goto 2
//goto 2 done
//goto 1 done
```

Note that this behaviour only seems to happen if we've previously downloaded some external files. Otherwise we get

output:

```
//goto 1
//goto 1 done
//goto 2
//goto 2 done
```

as we'd expect.

The workround we've come up with is to put all our gotoAndStop commands into a new function:

```
package {
    public function fGoToFrame(tClip:MovieClip, tFrame:*):void {
        pIgnoreFrameEventFromGoToAndStop = true;
        tClip.gotoAndStop(tFrame);
        pIgnoreFrameEventFromGoToAndStop = false;
    }
    // frame event:
    public function fAction(e:Event):void {
        if (! pIgnoreFrameEventFromGoToAndStop)
        {
            //...

        }
    }
}
```

That seems to prevent any of the bugs, but it's not exactly satisfying. I'd like to know why gotoAndStop on a child movieClip would trigger a frame event on the root sprite at all! And is there any way of stopping it without using this hack?

Comment: You should specify where you place Your code named "Bit of code".
This Question is unclear and need more code to test Your project.
Please try to edit Your question, I have no time to waste to rebuild Your classes and test this code.
I don't downnvote Your question because You're seems to be unfamiliar with the rules on stackoverflow.
It seems to be interesting to get more code to edit it, or propose an answer. ;)
Have a nice day.
Best regards.
Nicolas.
@DannyKodicek

Comment: I think, adding a diagram of the display tree structure in question would help.

Comment: Hi, Nicolas and Nox. I appreciate the comments. I do seem to struggle to get any questions answered here because my inclination is always to try to focus on the core of the problem and not overwhelm it with vast amounts of probably extraneous detail - my project has hundreds of classes. Mostly I'm more interested in general hints than specific lines of code and I guess SO is not the place to find those.